# Bash get uniq elements and filter the values

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, unix

New to bash.
I have a text file test.txt in which there is two keys one is **user_type** and other is **user**. Currently **user_type** has two types of values either "admin" or "guest" and **user** can have any type of value

```
     {  user_type: admin
        user: john    
             }
     { user_type: guest
       user: doe               
      }

     {user_type: admin
      user: test 
         }

     { user_type: admin
       user: something 
       } ........
```

I am trying to get uniq values in **user_type** using

```
    cat man.txt|sort|uniq
```

but it does not seems to work.

1. How to get  a  uniq value associated with user_type key ?

2.How to filter the values on the basis of **users** and count the **user_type** value?I have an array which has values

```
 array = (doe,test)  #This array can have any values from the user values of man.txt
```

Note:This array is generated from a api request which has some criterion for selecting the "users" and I only want to count the user_type value associated with the values in array

Now I only want the **user_type** value associated with that array.
   and count the **user_types** values that how many times particular type is repeated.

```
 for i in ${array[@]};do
     grep -c $i man.txt
```

but it is returning output:

```
     user:doe
  or user:test
```

but it doesn't return the count of particular values of user_type?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out.I fixed it

Comment: Can you explain more on 2) how the array is formed, it is not clear

Comment: Is this a broken `JSON` file you are trying to manipulate here?

Comment: I explained the array formation.Actually the JSON file is generated by me from API request by using    "some API request"|jq '.[]|{"user_type": .user_type,"user":  .group.user}

Comment: If you are comfortable with `jq` then why use `grep`?

Comment: Can you provide the complete syntax fixed `JSON` full complete file?

Comment: If you only care about the user types, it might be as simple as `grep -o 'user_type:.*' | sort | uniq -c`.  If you need to pair that information with other lines, you will be better off using a language like awk, python, or perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can be certain that the file has the lines always in the order: `user_type`, `user`, then you can just do something like:

```
array=("test" "doe")
for username in "${array[@]}"; do
    grep -B1 "$username" man.txt | grep -o 'user_type:.*' | sort | uniq -c
done
```

Where `grep -B1` outputs one line above the match, then we match that to get only the `user_type` output, piping to `sort` and counting the lines with `uniq`.